# Vue.js render child component to variable to be used within component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using **webpack** and **vue.js 2** and **vue-google-maps**.
I have an issue where i need to pass to a google maps component via a `prop` a rendered `vue-template`.

e.g.

```
    <gmap-info-window 
     :options="infoOptions" 
     :position="infoWindowPos" 
     :opened="infoWinOpen" 
     :content="infoContent" 
     @closeclick="infoWinOpen=false">
     </gmap-info-window>
```

i need to pass to the `:content` prop. something along the lines of this:

```
<p>
  Some Name 
  <a :href="some.url" target="_blank" @click="myFunction('param1', $route.name, param2)">some link</a>
<p>
```

basically i need `infoContent` to be the vue compiled version of the above. I can get the template e.g. by doing:

```
this.infoContent = myTemplate;
```

but that only gets me the raw unrendered version of the template if i add `.render()` to that i start getting errors about `_vm._self is undefined"`

Comment: Something like [this](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/zdKoGE?editors=1010)? The example builds a html template and gets the rendered HTML using `$el`.

Comment: Yeah i guess kinda, i mean ultimately i dont want to do dom manipulation i just want it to be saved the dom + the click action to a variable to be used as i need it.